# How do I display millisecond in my stopwatch?

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I am implementing a stopwatch by using Javascript. I have basic html document setup and a javascript file called stopwatch.js in which I have the following code. I make use of `setInterval` function to execute the `clockRunning` function every 1 second(1000ms). This gives me control over sec, min and hour to increment them accordingly, but I am having difficulty with inserting millisecond into the stopwatch. How should I increment the millisecond from 0 to 1000 and then reset to zero?

I have tried by decreasing the interval time for `setInterval` function to be called every 1ms and then set `millisecond` variable to `time%1000` in which `time` variable is increased by 1 every time the function is called. But it does not give the result I want. The `millisecond` seems to be increasing way too slow.

```js
var running = 0
var time = 0;
var hour = 0;
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;
var millisec = 0;


function start(){
 started = window.setInterval(clockRunning, 1000); 
}

function stop(){
 window.clearInterval(started);
}

function clockRunning(){
 time++;
 sec++;
 if (sec == 60){
  min += 1;
  sec = 0;
 if (min == 60){
  hour += 1;
  min = 0;
 }
 
 
 }

 document.getElementById("display-area").innerHTML = (hour ? (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) : "00") 
 + ":" + (min ? (min > 9 ? min : "0" + min) : "00") + ":" + (sec > 9 ? sec : "0" 
  + sec);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <script src="stopwatch.js"></script>
        <style>
            #display-area { font-size: 20pt; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <output id="display-area">00:00:00.000</output>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="toggle-button" onClick="start()">Start</button>
            <button id="toggle-button" onClick="stop()">Stop</button>
            <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/electricg/4372563

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should keep track of the starting time then subtract that time from the current time using a `Date`:

```js
var timeBegan = null
    , timeStopped = null
    , stoppedDuration = 0
    , started = null;

function start() {
    if (timeBegan === null) {
        timeBegan = new Date();
    }

    if (timeStopped !== null) {
        stoppedDuration += (new Date() - timeStopped);
    }
    console.log(stoppedDuration);

    started = setInterval(clockRunning, 10); 
}

function stop() {
    timeStopped = new Date();
    clearInterval(started);
}
 
function reset() {
    clearInterval(started);
    stoppedDuration = 0;
    timeBegan = null;
    timeStopped = null;
    document.getElementById("display-area").innerHTML = "00:00:00.000";
}

function clockRunning(){
    var currentTime = new Date()
        , timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - timeBegan - stoppedDuration)
        , hour = timeElapsed.getUTCHours()
        , min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes()
        , sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds()
        , ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();

    document.getElementById("display-area").innerHTML = 
        (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" + 
        (min > 9 ? min : "0" + min) + ":" + 
        (sec > 9 ? sec : "0" + sec) + "." + 
        (ms > 99 ? ms : ms > 9 ? "0" + ms : "00" + ms);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Stopwatch</title>
        <style>
            #display-area { font-size: 20pt; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <output id="display-area">00:00:00.000</output>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id="toggle-button" onClick="start()">Start</button>
            <button id="toggle-button" onClick="stop()">Stop</button>
            <button id="reset-button" onClick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The reason you were seeing the milliseconds "lagging" before was that `setInterval` is notorious for not firing *exactly* when you specify. You can get around this using the strategy above.

*Update*: You could keep track of how long the timer has "paused" between resets. Updated my answer to accommodate this.

Comment: There is an issue here. Even though `clearInterval` stops the clock, the counting does not seem to be stopping. I clicked on `stop` and then after a few seconds, clicked on the `start` again and this time, the time was already lapsed by a few second. I mean it does not restart/resume from the time it stops. Any idea how to implement this `resume` function?

Comment: Holy smoke! This is working now :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**complete code here**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var milliseconds;
    var hours;
    var minutes;
    var seconds;
    var interval;
    var count = 0;
    var lap;
    var i = 0;
    $(".heading").slideDown("slow"); //slide down heading countdown.

    // click function to start timer
    $(".start").click(function () {
      $(".start").hide();
      $(".pause").show(100);    // show pause button
      $("#end").text("Stopwatch Started"); // change text.
      interval = setInterval(newtimer, 10); // run the countdown interval of 1000 millisecond
    });

    function newtimer() {
      hours = parseInt(count * 10 / 1000 / 60 / 60);// calculate hours
      minutes = parseInt(count * 10 / 1000 / 60);  // calculate minutes
      seconds = parseInt((count * 10 / 1000)%60);// calculate seconds
      milliseconds = parseInt((count*10) % 1000); // calculate milliseconds
      /* display digits in clock manner */
      hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
      count++; // increment in count.
      $(".seconds").text(hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds + " : " + milliseconds);
    }

    /* click function to pause timer*/
    $(".pause").click(function () {
      $(".start").hide();      //hide start button
      $(".restart").hide();  //hide restart button
      $(".pause").hide();
      $(".resume").show();  // show resume button.
      $("#end").text("Stopwatch Paused");
      clearInterval(interval);  //clear interval will stop the count.
      i = i + 1;
      lap = " " + hours + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds + " : " + milliseconds;
      $(".lap").append('<p>' + 'Time Lap' + "-" + i + lap + '</p>'); // add p tag in div and count no. of laps.
    });

    /* click function to resume the countdown */
    $(".resume").click(function () {
      $("#end").text("Stopwatch Resumed");// change end text.
      $(".pause").show();
      $(".resume").hide();
      interval = setInterval(newtimer, 10);// interval to function new timer. count will remain same where paused.
    });

    /* click function to stop stopwatch */
    $(".stop").click(function () {
      $("#end").text("Stopwatch Stopped");
      $(".restart").show();   //show restart button
      $(".resume").hide();    // hide resume button
      $(".start").hide();// hide start button
      $(".pause").hide();
      $(".lap p").remove();   // remove laps.
      clearInterval(interval);
    });

    /*click function to restart stopwatch*/
    $(".restart").click(function () {
      $("#end").text("Stopwatch Restarted");// change end text.
      $(".restart").hide();
      $(".pause").show();
      count = 0;      // count reset  to zero
      interval = setInterval(newtimer, 10); //time interval to function new timer
    });
    /* click function on class reset to reset the countdown */
    $(".reset").click(function () {
      $(".seconds").text("00 : 00 : 00 : 00"); // set display to initial value.
      $(".resume").hide();   // hide resume button
      $(".start").show();   // show start button
      $(".pause").hide();   // hide pause button
      $(".restart").hide();  // hide restart button
      $("#end").text(" ");   // change end text
      $(".lap p").remove();  // remove p tag from div
      clearInterval(interval);  // clear interval
      count = 0;               // reset count to initial value.
    });
  })

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>stopwatch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
           integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<body style="font-family: cursive;">
<div class="container-fluid clearfix" style="padding:100px; background-color:lightgrey;">
    <div style="width:25%; float:left"><img src="./bn.jpg" alt="stopwatch" style="width:100%"></div>
    <div class="heading" style="color:#165caa;display:none;margin-left: 365px;font-size: 84px">STOPWATCH</div>
    <div class="seconds" style="font-size: 46px;text-align:center;margin-top:30px "> 00 : 00 : 00 : 00</div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <button class="start mt-3 px-4 btn btn-success">START</button>
        <button class="restart mt-3 px-4 btn btn-success" style="display:none">RESTART</button>
        <button class="resume mt-3 px-4 btn btn-success" style="display:none">RESUME</button>
        <button class="pause mt-3 px-4 btn btn-warning" style="display: none">PAUSE</button>
        <button class="stop  mt-3 px-4 btn btn-dark">STOP</button>
        <button class="reset mt-3 px-4 btn btn-danger">RESET</button>
    </div>
    <p id="end" style="font-size:32px ;margin-top:30px;text-align:center"></p>
    <div class="lap" style="text-align: center; font-size:16px;font-family: monospace;"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**BUG FIX!!!**

I noticed the Start, Stop, Reset would not work if you hit Start more than once with the code above. I was able to fix this by tweaking the start function!

```
function start() {

if (timeBegan === null) {
    timeBegan = new Date();
}else {
    clearInterval(started);
};

if (timeStopped !== null) {
    stoppedDuration += (new Date() - timeStopped);
};

if (stoppedDuration < 1000){
    console.log(stoppedDuration+' ms');
};

if (stoppedDuration > 1000){
    console.log(stoppedDuration/1000+' seconds');
};

started = setInterval(clockRunning, 10);

return stoppedDuration  }
```